# Can I add Defiance to my Steam account?

Tags: steam, defiance

I've purchased Defiance, and I'm familiar with adding external games to Steam. My question is, can I add Defiance to my Steam account where I would be able to download it from Steam directly? I did try adding the key in the retail box.

Comment: if you tried adding the key and it didn't work, then no, you can't do it without repurchasing it through steam

Comment: You could ask the publisher if they're willing to provide you with a Steam key, but there's no guarantee it'll work. When I asked EA for a key for *Crysis* and *The Sims 3*, they answered: "*We generally do not provide keys for platforms other than our own*"

Comment: @Nolonar little wonder, they're desperate for people to use Origin.

Answer (score 1):

If you purchased Defiance outside of Steam, I don't believe you'll be able to add it as a "native" Steam game, without already having a Steam key. The retail key you have will only work for a retail copy, or a direct download. Like you said, you'll be able to add Defiance externally though.

It also depends on where you purchased the game from. Some companies or publishers provide a Steam key if asked (or do so automatically upon purchase). Though, as Nolonar has stated, there's no guarantee for this. In general, I would say you need to buy a game from steam, in order to download the data required directly from the Steam servers.